# Memcache Error? "Could not find specified socket in poll list."

Tags: mac-osx-server, memcached

For some reason recently I've been getting this error in my apache error log on my server. We have a single instance of memcached running on our Mac OSX 10.7 server.

(20014)Internal error: Unknown memcached error while writing: Could not find specified socket in poll list.

I can't find anything about this error message online :. Does anyone have any idea what could cause it or how I can try debugging it? There's a memcached-tools(?) function on linux, but it doesn't seem to be on the Mac...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to have been because we were missing an instance of memcache running. We have our subversion setup to use memcache on port 11213, so I just started another instance of memcached on 11213 (`memcached -dp 11213`), and everything is good again!